# How to make jQuery Validator remotely trigger errorPlacement?

Tags: php, jquery, validation

Can anyone please tell me how I can get the **[jQuery Validator](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions)** to call the **`errorPlacement`** handler when a **`remote`** function fails? I have provided a short example:

**Cliff Notes:** According to their documents, I have to output JSON, but I must have missed something because do I just echo out json_encode, or do I provide a key like `echo json_encode(array('result' => 0))` as it says in this **[block of text](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote#options)**.

**JS:**

```
var validator = $("form#signup").validate({
    onfocousout: true,
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            remote: {
                type: "POST",
                url: 'test.php',
                data: {
                    email: function() {return $("#email").val();}
                }
            }
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, el) {
            console.log('ERR' + $(el).attr('id'));
        }
    }
});
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
echo false; // This should allow the errorPlacement to call shouldn't it?
```

Comment: You might want to echo `json_encode(FALSE)`, since now you echo nothing at all.  (But nothing should trigger the error as well if I'm understanding the source correctly.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to echo `false` as a string from your PHP script:

```
<?php
echo 'false';
```

I've created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J7swe/) based on your question. The pastebin link just returns the word "false".

Comment: This is way ugly. As Zombaya said, `json_encode(FALSE)` is the way to go.

Comment: theoretically, `json_encode(FALSE)` does not produce valid JSON, since valid JSON has either an array or an object at its top level